# Captured Image from my application get rotated in only samsung device

Tags: android

i am working on camera app where i have take picture without using device camera, i have did and it's working fine but when we capture image on samsung devices i am getting rotated image into onPictureTaken callback method.

Please let me know what should i do to get image in same orientation as device orientation.

I am using following code to set camera rotation but it does not help in samsung device.

```
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);
        int rotation = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break; //Natural orientation
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break; //Landscape left
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;//Upside down
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;//Landscape right
        }
        int rotate = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;

        Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
        param.setRotation(rotate); 
        mCamera.setParameters(param);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an interesting suggestion, which I also did in one of my projects. I assume you are using an imageView and a Bitmap. Now convert your rotation code to a method that rotates 90 degrees. Then add a transparent button over the image. At each click on the image (the button also), the image will rotate 90 degrees!!
For example, you can write a rotation method like this;

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source)
{
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(90);
      return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Then, assuming that you have added a transparent button "rotater" over the image, you can set it's onClickListener as follows. It both sets the Bitmap and imageView.

```
rotater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            originalBitmap=rotateBitmap(originalBitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);

        }
    });
```

Image rotation is a problem because of EXIF data of images. Hope this trick suits your need.